# Limpieza de un inputex con evento ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces

tengo la siguiente consulta,
tengo un inputtext que me apunta a un metodo.

```
<p:remoteCommand  name="test" actionListener="#{bodegaController.eventoPistola}"/>
                        <p:inputText id="it" value="#{bodegaController.codigoBarras}" placeholder="Codigo de barras"
                                     onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                                                 test();
                                                 return false;
                                             }">
                            <p:ajax event="keyup" update=":form:dtPedidoEncontrado"/>
                        </p:inputText>
```

Metodo java

```
public void eventoPistola() {
    System.out.println("Codigo Barras: " + codigoBarras);
    PickingPedidos pickingPedidoEncontrado = null;
    for (PickingPedidos pp : pickingPedidosList) {
        System.out.println("---> " + pp.getMProductId() + ", " + pp.getDocumentno() + ", " + pp.getCodigoBarras() + ", " + pp.getProducto() + ", " + pp.getCodigo() + ", " + pp.getExistencia());
        if (pp.getCodigoBarras().equals(codigoBarras)) {
            pickingPedidoEncontrado = pp;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pickingPedidoEncontrado != null) {
        System.out.println("Encontrado !!!!");
        pedidoEncontrado = new PedidoEncontrado();
        pedidoEncontrado.setCodigoBarras(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getCodigoBarras());
        pedidoEncontrado.setDocumento(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getDocumentno());
        pedidoEncontrado.setFactor(factor);
        pedidoEncontrado.setPedida(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getPedida());
        pedidoEncontrado.setProductId(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getMProductId());
        pedidoEncontrado.setNombreProducto(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getProducto());
        pedidoEncontrado.setCodigo(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getCodigo());
        pedidoEncontrado.setNumeroDeCaja(numeroDeCajas);
        pedidoEncontrado.setExistencia(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getExistencia().intValue());
        pickingPedidos = new PickingPedidos();
        pedidoEncontradoList.add(pedidoEncontrado);
        codigoBarras = null;

    } else {

        System.out.println("NO encontrado :(");
    }

}
```

Pero resulta que la variable java codigoBarras en el metodo efectivamente que da nula pero en mi vista no se limpia.

```
<p:remoteCommand  name="test" actionListener="#{bodegaController.eventoPistola}"/>
                        <p:inputText id="it" value="#{bodegaController.codigoBarras}" placeholder="Codigo de barras"
                                     onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                                                 test();
                                                 return false;
                                             }">
                            <p:ajax event="keyup" update=":form:dtPedidoEncontrado :form:it"/>
                        </p:inputText>
```

Ni poniendolo de esta forma.

Cualquier ayuda estare muy agradecido.

Comment: Lo que te falta es agregar un update al remotecommand asi <p:remoteCommand update="it" />

Comment: Hola Raul no aun no limpia.

Comment: Que podra ser. @RaulCacacho

Comment: prueba en el update @form para que fresque todo el formulario

Comment: Listo si señor me limpia todo el form pero aun no me limpia el componente inputtext @RaulCacacho

Comment: En ese caso puede ser que entre al else ahi no se limpia codigoBarra

Comment: Gracias @RaulCacacho ya dio una pregunta yo lo podria contactar para unas asesorias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no se esta actualizando el campo, lo puedes de una manera controlada usando `@form` en el `update` de esta manera:

```
p:remoteCommand update="@form" name="test" actionListener="#{bodegaController.eventoPistola}"/>
```

El `@form` actualizara todo el formulario.